# Поиск по массиву

Tags: массивы, php

Здравствуйте.

Есть массив:

```
$array = array(); $array[] = 'привет всем'; $array[] = 'privet vsem';
```

Какой функцией можно найти массив по вхождению "всем"?

Наработки:

```
if(array_search('всем', $array)) echo '1';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то вроде как нет такой функции, но свою то написать не проблема

```
function my_array_search($needle, $array)
{
     $result = array();
     foreach($array as $key => $value)
     {
          if(strpos($value, $needle) !== false)
          {
                $result[$key] = $value;
          }
     }
     return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$array1 = array("всем прив", "привет", "всем", "всем тут привет", "яяя");
$str='всем';
function my_seach($var)
{
    global $str;    
    return (strpos($var, $str) !== false);
}
print_r (array_filter($array1, "my_seach"));
```

выводится

```
Array ( [0] => всем прив [2] => всем [3] => всем тут привет )
```

Comment: Не самое лучшее решение, тут доработочки нужны. К примеру, добавьте в массив фразу, содержащую слово "повсеместно" и функция этот элемент массива "за родного" примит.

Comment: как вопрос поставили, так ответ и получили. В вопросе не говорится что вхождение должно быть именно отдельным словом(
Да я думаю у автора стоит больше вопрос не как найти вхождение у отдельного элемента массива, а как красиво это сделать по всем элементам массива